# Insert values into a data frame in a loop R

Tags: r

I want to paste in the stay column the value I get through this function. 
This is the df (the df contains more than 85000000 of rows with differents mac_address and sensors):

```
> head(df)
                        id   device_type direction       mac_address
1 5b83072ce72db73f1c3dd874 Mobile device     input 00:00:00:00:00:00
2 5b83077ce72db73f1c3dd902 Mobile device    output 00:00:00:00:00:00
3 5b832c45e72db73f1c3e0550 Mobile device     input 00:00:00:00:00:00
4 5b832c96e72db73f1c3e0589 Mobile device    output 00:00:00:00:00:00
5 5b83f783e72db73f1c3f0847 Mobile device     input 00:00:00:00:00:00
6 5b83f7d4e72db73f1c3f08f7 Mobile device    output 00:00:00:00:00:00
  processed_status rssi signal_type          fecha_hora sensor      uTime stay
1            FALSE  -72          WF 2018-08-26 22:00:08    3_2 1535313608   -1
2            FALSE  -90          WF 2018-08-26 22:01:54    3_2 1535313714   -1
3            FALSE  -71          WF 2018-08-27 00:38:21    3_2 1535323101   -1
4            FALSE  -90          WF 2018-08-27 00:40:10    3_2 1535323210   -1
5            FALSE  -74          WF 2018-08-27 15:06:03    3_2 1535375163   -1
6            FALSE  -90          WF 2018-08-27 15:07:40    3_2 1535375260   -1
```

And this is the fuction that get the cluster for each mac_addres and sensor and the following error:

```
> mac <- as.data.frame(unique(df$mac_address))
> sens <- as.data.frame(unique(df$sensor))
> for (i in 1:nrow(mac)) {
+   for (j in 1:nrow(sens)) {
+     cluster <- dbscan(df[df$mac_address == mac[i,] & df$sensor == sens[j,], ]$uTime, eps = 300, MinPts = 2)
+    df$stay <- cbind(df[df$mac_address == mac[i,] & df$sensor == sens[j,], ], stay = cluster$cluster)
+ #Add the cluster$cluster to the df 
+       
+   }
+ }
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "stay", value = list(id = c(1755538L,  : 
replacement has 16 rows, data has 8324325
```

With this function I get a cluster value for each single mac_address and sensor. But I can't add this cluster number to the df, because in the loop it's iterated by mac_address and sensor and it gives me the following error.

I don't know if there's a better way to do it, but that's what I've come up with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `dbscan`? Per `r` tag (hover or click to see): specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls.

Comment: DBSCAN y a clustering algorithm, returns the value of the cluster to which it belongs

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are assigning a non-filtered data frame column by filtered data result in `cbind` call  where both sides have different rows:

```
df$stay <- cbind(df[df$mac_address == mac[i,] & df$sensor == sens[j,], ], 
                 stay = cluster$cluster)
```

Also, assuming `dbScan` from the same named package, [CRAN docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/dbscan.pdf) indicate return value is:

> An object of class ’dbscan_fast’ with the following components:
>
> **eps** value of the eps parameter. 
> **minPts**  value
>   of the minPts parameter. 
> **cluster**  A integer vector with
>   cluster assignments. Zero indicates noise points.

Which may extend R's `list` object with these named vector components and not a single value. Additionally, your data frame filter may return no rows as there may be no instances of a specific unique value of *mac_address* AND *sensor*.  Altogether, you have length issues on both sides of assignment.

To fix, consider wrapping calculation in `tryCatch` and specifically selecting `eps` value. Also, consider `expand.grid` and `Map` for elementwise looping instead of nested `for` loops where you build an intermediate data frame that merges back to larger one:

```
# DATA FRAME OF ALL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS
params_df <- expand.grid(mac_address = unique(df$mac_address),
                         sensor = unique(df$sensor))

# USER-DEFINED METHOD WITH tryCatch FOR FAILED CALCULATIONS
calc_cluster <- function(mac, sens) {
    tryCatch({
       sub <- df[df$mac_address == mac & df$sensor == sens,]
       dbscan(sub$uTime, eps = 300, MinPts = 2)$eps
     }, error = function(e) return(NA)
    )
}

# COLUMN ASSIGNMENT
params_df$cluster <- Map(calc_cluster, params_df$mac_address, params_df$sensor)

# MERGE TO ORIGINAL DATA FRAME
df <- merge(df, params_df, by=c("mac_address", "sensor"))
```